# ActionMailer loop on rake task send an extra mail every time it runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, actionmailer

I cannot figure this out, 
I have this class

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 def apps_remainder_email()
    #apps array ..which basically have 3 records in it
    apps.each do |rec||
    mail(to:  user.email, subject: 'Apps Remainder').deliver
    end
 end
end
```

When I try to call the above in rails console `UserMailer.apps_remainder_email` it is working fine and sending out three emails, but When I add this as a rake task it sends out four instead of three i.e always a duplicate of final email.

Here is my rake task

```
task daily: [:environment] do  
 UserMailer.apps_remainder_email.deliver
end
```

I think it is because I have a .deliver in my task, but without that .deliver no mails are sending at all.

```
  $ rake daily --trace
    ** Invoke daily (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Execute daily
```

Comment: In the code above you have `apps_remainder_email` and in the task you call `appointment_remainder_email`. Is this only a typo?

Comment: ah sorry! edited it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UserMailer` class should not call `deliver` by itself.

Instead your rake task should call `deliver`.

So remove `deliver` from the `UserMailer` class and place the logic into your rake task:

```
task daily: [:environment] do  
   apps.each do |rec||
      UserMailer.apps_remainder_email(rec).deliver
   end
end
```